# UTF-8 websites in trouble with particular browsers

Tags: jquery, json, oracle, jsp, character-encoding

I have build a web application with a presentation layer using JSP.
In every JSP I have defined charset like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
...
```

If user wants to edit information for user profile, I load the object in a form.
If the page has been access in **Opera**, **Chrome**, **Safari** or **IE 10** (on Windows 7) once I send the form to the back-end (Java) and the data is merged in database, some characters are badly stored.
Mainly: á, é, í, ó, ú, ...
But with **Firefox** there are no problems.

I am running Oracle 11g and this is the charset:

```
SQL> select * from v$nls_parameters;

PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE
SPANISH

NLS_TERRITORY
SPAIN

NLS_CURRENCY
Ç


PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY
SPAIN

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS
,.

NLS_CALENDAR
GREGORIAN


PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT
DD/MM/RR

NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
SPANISH

NLS_CHARACTERSET
AL32UTF8


PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_SORT
SPANISH

NLS_TIME_FORMAT
HH24:MI:SSXFF

NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF


PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT
HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR

NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT
DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR

NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY
Ç


PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET
AL16UTF16

NLS_COMP
BINARY

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS
BYTE


PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP
FALSE


19 rows selected.
```

I have checked to edit profiles in other computers and the result is the same.
I don't know where the problem can be, any help? Thanks

**Update:** The JS code on form submit:

```
$(function() {
    $('#user-update').submit(function(event) {    
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/user/${user.userId}/update',                    
            data : JSON.stringify($('#user-update').serializeObject()),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function() {
            ...
```

Comment: check also HTTP headers sent from your server.

Comment: @sodik I am using `$.ajax()` function. Shall I be explicit with charset then? THanks

Comment: if you really gets different result with different browsers, it is very likely the problem. try capture your request with FF (firebug->network) and in chrome(developer tools->network) and check HTTP headers if they are any (and or if they differ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `CharacterEncodingFilter` in my `web.xml` file:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content encoding of the page isn't related to the encoding of submitted form data in any way (well, in any way that you care about, anyway).

I'm a bit worried about `JSON.stringify($('#user-update').serializeObject())`. The call to `stringify` isn't necessary; jQuery will do that for you. This should be enough:

```
data: $('#user-update').serializeObject(),
```

This should also solve all encoding problems between browser and server - jQuery will make sure of that.

To help to debug this issue, you will have to add logging in the following places:

```
console.log($('#user-update').serializeObject());
```

before the AJAX request. You can also use the developer tools for your web browser to see the network requests and responses.

On the server side, log the data that you get to make sure you don't pump garbage into the database. Then use an SQL tool to query the data in the database to make sure it's saved in the correct way.

Lastly, log the data after your code read it from the database again.

In the future, I suggest to write unit tests for each of the steps above because that would have prevented this mess in the first place :-)

Comment: Yes, I have unit tests for my service and dao layers. That's why I thought the problem what with the Javascript side (which I have less knowledge about..). You are right on my serialization... I had no idea how to do it easier. Finally I think I solve it by adding a `characterEncodingFilter` in server. I will post my answer shortly. Thanks for your answer!